# Como segurar o valor de um POST entre paginação no CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um elemento `form` com um `select` e um `submit` (filtrar). Os dados são filtrados, a pagina é recarregada e os dados são apresentados em uma tabela. Para ver todos os dados, passa-se por mais de uma pagina na tabela (paginação). No entanto, eu utilizo um valor que vem de do valor do ultimo `POST` (conteúdo do `select`) e quando eu troco de pagina na tabela, a tabela passa a mostrar os dados do primeiro elemento do `select`, pois não guarda o valor do `POST`.

Como eu posso guardar o valor do post para que as paginas depois da primeira sejam mostradas também?

Answer (score 4):

Ao invés de `POST`, você pode passar o valor desse `<select>` via `GET` e colocá-lo em sua paginação.

Exemplo do link sem o filtro:

`pagina.php?p=3`

Exemplo do link com o filtro:

`pagina.php?p=3&filtro=teste`

Poste algum código para que possamos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Realmente, parece fazer mais sentido utilizar GET.

Comment: @DiegoSouza digo por experiência própria. Filtros em get podem ser feios, porém via post são piores no ponto de vista do usuário, que não pode favoritar uma url com seus filtros preferidos por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa forma é usar session, tipo ao preencher o form e enviar armazena os dados do post em sassion, e o seu filtro passa a recuperar as informações do session.

assim conseguirá transferir seus dados de post de uma página para outra.

Comment: Para esse tipo de operação (pesquisas e, principalmente, as com paginação), é sempre bom usar o método `GET` mesmo, pois o mesmo é o mais apropriado para isso.