# Como passar parâmetros dinamicamente para o Rails?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

tenho um problema meio complexo ao extremo. Eu preciso de alguma forma, passar parâmetros dinamicamente para o params via javascript, para mostrar/ocultar alguns campos em um relatório a pedido do usuário. Abaixo segue uma representação da tela:

[image: Demonstração de como a UI funciona.]

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário entra com os dados que ele quer na busca, com remote: true. Ali acima tenho um container com um grupo de checkboxes, que é o meu problema no momento. Ali abaixo é onde os resultados são carregados de um partial com um arquivo .js.erb. Importante citar que apenas essa parte recarrega.

A caixa com as checkboxes, não faz parte de um formulário, e ao meu pensar nem deveriam. No JavaScript, eu tenho um evento atrelado a cada checkbox. Quando cada um é desmarcado, o campo correspondente na tabelas de resultados é ocultado e um hidden field é criado e inserido dinamicamente no formulário ali à esquerda. Sendo assim, eu consigo enviar esses parâmetros via url na hora do submit e ocultar esses campos com uma condicional dando um display: none nas linhas em que o parâmetro tiver valor 1. Isso funciona se o usuário efetuar a filtragem. Mas se ela não for efetuada, os parâmetros não são enviados para a URL e quando a paginação é feita, as linhas que deveriam ser ocultadas aparecem.

Gostaria de saber então se há uma forma de enviar esses parâmetros para o hash params dinamicamente via AJAX, pra tudo funcionar corretamente com, ou sem a filtragem...

Comment: Ver também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9923/como-segurar-o-valor-de-um-post-entre-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-codeigniter/9926#9926 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12241/como-passar-vari%C3%A1veis-entre-p%C3%A1ginas-php-via-javascript (duplicatas?)

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria da seguinte maneira: 
Colocaria meu form envolvendo tudo e tiraria o Javascript que adiciona os campos ocultos no form.

A paginação seria botões de submit com o name a pagina que você deseja.

Com isso cada vez que o usuário clicar em uma nova página, irá submeter o form e enviar junto com os parâmetros a paginação que desejar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]